# Get the root domain from url using angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have different url for sites like

> http://www.abc.com.mypros.fit.edu.co
>
> http://www.abc.com.mypros.library.org

How can I get root domain

> mypros.fit.edu.co
>
> mypros.library.org

using typescript in angular 6+

I'm using **window.location.host** but this does not help, because it returns the url where I need the root url.

Answer (score 0):

If your url always starts the same, try using a simple replace:

```
url.replace('http://www.example.com.','');
```

Comment: some time it use different proxy like 0-www.abc.com.mypros.library.edu

Comment: either you can just replace all possible url names or you can use a regular expression that matches them